# Why do I receive the <a> cannot be a descendant of <a>?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

Here is what the inspector tells me when I load up my portfolio page. I am using the latest version of React.

```
14:47:22.595 Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <a> cannot appear as a descendant of <a>.
a
O@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:70118:6
a
div
div
Web
div
div
div
Header@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1746:78
div
div
Home
App react-dom.development.js:67
    React 16
    js index.js:7
    factory react refresh:6
    Webpack 3
```

Not sure if that issue could explain why one of the images for one section are not displaying while the other ones are, but it's the only error I saw that was not the standard child of prop.

This is the repo for the Portfolio: https://github.com/kstaver/React-Portfolio-v2

Comment: Because you have an `<a>` tag as a grandchild of another `<a>` tag, can they can't be nested

Comment: i.e. as documented *Permitted content: Transparent, except that no descendant may be interactive content or an `a` element, and no descendant may have a specified `tabindex` attribute.* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#properties